# Changing Dataframe type with an exception

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few pandas dataframe that consist of 1 column and 5 rows, each dataframe contains 3 values, "1", "0", and "P". These data frames are of type "object".

I am running into problems when i am adding data frames together. il give you an example:

```
df1 = [ 1, P, 0, 1, 1]
df2 = [1, P, 1, 1,1]
df1 + df2 = [11, PP, 01, 11,11]
```

Note: A "P" will alway be in the same location in all data frames. so when adding together data frames i could get "PPPPP" for example.

In the example above i am trying to get the output to be:

```
df1 + df2 =  [2, P, 1, 2, 2]
```

What i am thinking is to use pandas to make each dataframe column numeric and then i should be able to add them together.

```
pd.to_numeric(df1["my df title"], errors='coerce')
```

the problem with this is that the "P" values cannot be converted to numeric. how to i make everything numeric except the p values?

what my real dataframe looks like when I add df1 + df2 + df3 + df4:

```
0     1111
1     PPPP
2     1111
3     1111
4     PPPP
```

Comment: can you add a proper example of your dataframe? all i see are three lists, you can `print(df.head(5).to_dict())` and paste the output here if the data is not sensitive.

Comment: i have added what the addition looks like.

Comment: `df1 = [ 1, P, 0, 1, 1]` is not a DataFrame, it's a list made of integers and a variable `P`. Please, post a fully reproducible code with your DataFrames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert each value to expected output with `if-else`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col': [ '1', 'P', '0', '1', '1']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col': [ '1', 'P', '1', '1', '1']})

s = df1['col'] + df2['col']

s = s.map(lambda x: 'P' if 'P' in x else sum(map(int, list(x))))
```

```
print(s)

0    2
1    P
2    1
3    2
4    2
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you, exactly what i was looking for